# Add custom legend to pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add custom legend. Right now,the legends are showing Column "a", instead can we show Column "legend" ? Because column "legend" has both label and values. Can we do this?:)

```
library('ggplot2')
asd <- data.frame(a = c("fds","fdsf"), b = c(3,4))
asd$legend <- paste0(asd$a,"-",asd$b)
ggplot(asd, aes(x="", y=b, fill = a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just map the fill to the `legend` column:

```r
ggplot(asd, aes(x = "", y = b, fill = legend)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]